# Is there a comprehensive manual regarding floats and their positioning?

Tags: floats

There are many questions/complaints about the positioning of floats (`figure` or `table`) on this site --- use `[H]` or `[htp]` or .... I have a vague memory that some years ago somebody produced a document that comprehensively detailed everything that you needed to know about how LaTeX positioned floats and how you could control that.

Being an old man with a fading memory I can't recall or find where this is available (perhaps somewhere on the TUG website).
Hopefully someone else will be able to point to it. It could be very helpful as a generic answer to float problems.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat

Comment: You wrote one yourself as part of the `memoir` manual. Though it does not cover `[H]` as `[H]` is not a part of `memoir`. I refer people to it from time to time as it is a good explanation about how the many settings work.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you had in mind, but FMi had one such article at TUG. See the 2014 one at https://www.latex-project.org/publications/indexbytopic/2e-floats/.

Comment: Is it somewhere within [Often referenced questions - TeX - LaTeX Meta Stack Exchange → Float](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2421/250119) ? // in any case there's also "the LaTeX2e unofficial reference manual", although it's not really linkable.

Comment: I think that I was thinking of Frank Mittelbach's 2014 article in TUGboat as referenced by @gusbrs, to whom thanks. Would you like to make it an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frank Mittelbach has one such TUGboat article: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb35-3/tb111mitt-float.pdf).  And an excellent one at that.

It is also available at https://www.latex-project.org/publications/indexbytopic/2e-floats/ alongside with the documentation of `fewerfloatpages` (also a TUGboat article), which may also be of interest.

And the original article was actually derived from an answer here on the site: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/105447) which, as [reminded by @user202729](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645794/is-there-a-comprehensive-manual-regarding-floats-and-their-positioning#comment1609321_645794) is the accepted answer to the first question on [Often referenced questions - TeX - LaTeX Meta Stack Exchange → Float](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2421/105447).